# calculations for a very large number

Tags: c#

I have a function which calculates the factorial and combinations as follows.

```
    int faktorial(int n)
    {
        if( (n == 0)||(n == 1))
        {
            return (1);
        }
        else
        {
            return (n * faktorial(n-1));
        }
    }

    int Kombinasi(int x, int y)
    {
        int n = faktorial(x);
        int k = (faktorial(x - y)) * (faktorial(y));
        int hasil = n / k;
        return (hasil);
    }
```

But there is a problem that in calculating the factorial. 
Suppose I want to count combination with x = 1000 and y = 4. The function of the combination of the existing call factorial function. but the factorial function is not able to count them. How to solve this problem ?. Sorry my english is very bad. thanks.

Comment: look into the [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: factorial for 1000 is a big big number, you will need to add numerics namespace and use bigInteger class, with your algorithm calculating the factorial of 1000 can take a long time, maybe using memoization or other approach can improve the calculation

Comment: If you are interested in a non-recursive factorial computer, you can check out [this part](https://github.com/spearson/xofz.Core/blob/master/xofz.Core/Framework/Computation/FactorialComputer.cs) of my library here.

Answer (score 2):

`BigInteger` works and is pretty fast at 1000!.

```
BigInteger faktorial(BigInteger n)
{
    if ((n == 0) || (n == 1))
    {
        return (1);
    }
    else
    {
        return (n * faktorial(n - 1));
    }
}

BigInteger Kombinasi(BigInteger x, BigInteger y)
{
    BigInteger n = faktorial(x);
    BigInteger k = (faktorial(x - y)) * (faktorial(y));
    BigInteger hasil = n / k;
    return (hasil);
}
```

Answer:

> 402387260077093773543702433923003985719374864210714632543799910429938512398629020592044208486969404800479988610197196058631666872994808558901323829669944590997424504087073759918823627727188732519779505950995276120874975462497043601418278094646496291056393887437886487337119181045825783647849977012476632889835955735432513185323958463075557409114262417474349347553428646576611667797396668820291207379143853719588249808126867838374559731746136085379534524221586593201928090878297308431392844403281231558611036976801357304216168747609675871348312025478589320767169132448426236131412508780208000261683151027341827977704784635868170164365024153691398281264810213092761244896359928705114964975419909342221566832572080821333186116811553615836546984046708975602900950537616475847728421889679646244945160765353408198901385442487984959953319101723355556602139450399736280750137837615307127761926849034352625200015888535147331611702103968175921510907788019393178114194545257223865541461062892187960223838971476088506276862967146674697562911234082439208160153780889893964518263243671616762179168909779911903754031274622289988005195444414282012187361745992642956581746628302955570299024324153181617210465832036786906117260158783520751516284225540265170483304226143974286933061690897968482590125458327168226458066526769958652682272807075781391858178889652208164348344825993266043367660176999612831860788386150279465955131156552036093988180612138558600301435694527224206344631797460594682573103790084024432438465657245014402821885252470935190620929023136493273497565513958720559654228749774011413346962715422845862377387538230483865688976461927383814900140767310446640259899490222221765904339901886018566526485061799702356193897017860040811889729918311021171229845901641921068884387121855646124960798722908519296819372388642614839657382291123125024186649353143970137428531926649875337218940694281434118520158014123344828015051399694290153483077644569099073152433278288269864602789864321139083506217095002597389863554277196742822248757586765752344220207573630569498825087968928162753848863396909959826280956121450994871701244516461260379029309120889086942028510640182154399457156805941872748998094254742173582401063677404595741785160829230135358081840096996372524230560855903700624271243416909004153690105933983835777939410970027753472000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

**Note**, however, that it appears to overflow the stack above around 8889!.

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your question - you can handle bigger values (up to 2^64 - 1) if you use

```
ulong c;
```

Second, a little help - that won't help you with the exercise. Even unsigned long won't be able to handle such large values. However, note that instead, to get (n choose k), you can simply calculate (n * (n - 1) * .... * (n - k + 1)) / k!, Which deals with much smaller values.

Comment: `unsigned long` is not a type in C#.

Comment: @Kyle old habits die hard. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like what you really want to do is compute a binomial coefficient, an alternative to using `BigInteger` is to take advantage of some of the numerical properties of factorials.  So rather than computing factorials directly (which can be large), you can instead do this:

```
long Kombinasi(long x, long y)
{
    if( y == 0 ) return 1;
    return ( x * Kombinasi( x - 1, y - 1 ) ) / y;
}
```

You could also use this algorithm in combination with `BigInteger` if you need even larger values:

```
BigInteger Binomial( BigInteger n, BigInteger k )
{
    if( k <= 0 ) return 1;
    return ( n * Binomial( n - 1, k - 1 ) ) / k;
}
```

This will be much more efficient than computing the factorials and dividing since it takes advantage of the fact that most of the factorial terms cancel out.  It will also perform fewer multiplications, especially if `k` is small.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other members We can use `BitInteger` for big numbers.
I dont know whether it is useful or not, but I want to explain one point here.

So lets say We have a signed int which has big value(`int.Max`) and If you try to add some positive integer value (10), It wont give you `System.OverflowException`. It simply give you negative value. So If you want to raise exception in such cases. You can use `checked` keyword. if the expression produces a value that is outside the range of the destination type. If the expression contains one or more non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow. Overflow checking can be enabled by use of the checked keyword. So when you try something like I mentioned above, It will throw exception and you can handle it accordingly.

[checked in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx)